# ngrx cascade multiple effects design

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I am trying to implement in Angular 5 cascaded async calls using ngrx effects. I came across this: [ngrx Effects: Are actions dispatched by one effect processed immediately by other effects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42731937/ngrx-effects-are-actions-dispatched-by-one-effect-processed-immediately-by-othe?rq=1)

Things would appreciate your help with:

1. If I want async A > async B > async C, should I use 3 effects and each to listen to the previous action and pass the data via payload? What is a good architecture to handle the sequential async?
2. In the above post, it mentions after action A is triggered in effect A reducer would be triggered. I am thinking why A reducer is triggered at all since A action is caught by B effect so A reducer should never run? Please help!

thank you!